# Wordpress and Xampp not open child pages

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I'm working with wordpress + xampp but I can not see the child pages.

Appears:

`Object not found!`

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on that page seems to be in an error or out of date. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server problem, please contact the webmaster.

error 404

`localhost
Apache / 2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL / 1.0.1l PHP / 5.6.8`

Comment: Can you access the site at all? If you can then try to update your permalinks by going to `Settings > Permalinks" in the administration. You should also make sure so that the `mod_rewrite` module is enabled on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Xampp has FollowSymlinks disabled. See point 4 on how to

- enable mod rewrite (if not done already)
- set AllowOverride from none to all

https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Fixing_Permalink_Problems

If AllowOverride is not set to all, permalinks will cause exactly these 404 errors you describe ("Not found" on existing pages).

Answer (score 1):

For others that might come across this issue but already have `mod_rewrite` enabled as I did, try creating `.htaccess` and making it writable.