# Wordpress: Object not found

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

I installed ZeroEngine theme and MarketEngine plugin on my Wordpress LocalHost with XAMPP (MAC OS Sierra) from [www.enginethemes.com] (https://www.enginethemes.com/member/content/MarketEngine.14).

From the listings menu in this WordPress plugin, If I click on the URL of any of the titles as highlighted in the attached listing page photo:

[image]

the error message below is displayed.

> **Object not found!**
>   The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
>   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404
>   localhost
>   Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30 mod_perl/2.0.

As usual, I've tried several options to solve the issue by contacting the plugin developer, they mentioned choosing a Permalink which I've tried by selecting "Post name" from setting and the issue is yet to be resolved. I've also read several posts about this error.

Comment: One of the URLs is: http://localhost/wp/listing/marketengine-sample-listing-9/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress and Xampp not open child pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894827/wordpress-and-xampp-not-open-child-pages)

Comment: I found clearing my browser's cache helped

Answer (score 2):

Updating permalinks worked for me

Settings > Permalinks > Click Save

Answer (score 1):

You have to config rewrite rules for wp's friendly links.
Be sure that mod_rewrite extension enabled.
Then you can create .htaccess file on your wp root directory with following lines:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    # dont rewrite existing files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    # dont rewrite existing directories
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    
    # END WordPress
```