# wordpress links in menu doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

i'm working on word-press to create eCommerce website and i have face same problem.
i'm working on PC using XAMPP in localhost server. i have create new page in word-press and after that when i have publish the page and then i click on view the page to see the page whose the page look like ,the page show error "object is not found".
also error in menu on website link navigation.

i have already set permalinks as post name.

and now i have search many time on google but i doesn't found any solution.

i'm very feel frustrating.
please help me to find out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are the links defined correctly in your database corresponding to your local Wordpress installation?

If yes, maybe FollowSymlinks are disabled and hence your Permalinks are not working correctly.

See the accepted answer from this SO thread:
[Wordpress and Xampp not open child pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894827/wordpress-and-xampp-not-open-child-pages)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
ini_set( 'log_errors', 1 );
ini_set( 'error_log', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug.log' );
```

add these lines in wp-config.php and then visit the page, this will not resolve the error but create a debug file in the wp-content folder so you can have the better idea where the issue is.. :)